# Fixing faucet leak -- any advice?

Tags: leak, faucet

I installed a faucet that has a sprayer.  However I have no use for the sprayer and no hole for sprayer installation. The line that would have attached to the sprayer is leaking. Is it better to get a new faucet with no sprayer or can I clamp this one reliably?  If I can clamp this one, should I attach the sprayer line and clamp or clamp the part attached to the installed faucet?  This is a delta Collins 440-ss-day.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the leak, or of where the sprayer hose attaches to the faucet, would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the sprayer hose is attached to the body of the valve with a fitting that would allow replacement of the hose. If so, you may be able to get a plug that would replace the hose in its entirety.